# Copying an XML file including doctype, entities and notations XSLT 3

Tags: xml, doctype, xslt-3.0, xml-entities

I have a series of XML documents that are being copied from one folder into another, transformed with msxsl.exe 1.1.0.1 and an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, then copied back to the original folder. I don't know why the doctype, entities and notations are not being copied over but currently they are being inserted with javascript in the style sheet. I have to replace the javascript with XSLT 3.0 so it will work with saxon HE11.

The doctype is the highest element in the XML, this is also my desired output:

```
  <!DOCTYPE dmodule [
  <!ENTITY ICN-XXX12-001-01 SYSTEM "ICN-XXX12-001-01.SWF" NDATA swf >
  <!ENTITY ICN-XXX49-001-01 SYSTEM "ICN-XXX49-001-01 SYSTEM.CGM" NDATA cgm >
  <!ENTITY ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01 SYSTEM "ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01.wrlzip" NDATA WRLZIP>
  <!NOTATION cgm PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//NOTATION Computer Graphics Metafile//EN" >
  <!NOTATION swf PUBLIC "-//S1000D//NOTATION X-SHOCKWAVE-FLASH 3D Models Encoding//EN" >
  <!NOTATION WRLZIP SYSTEM "WRLZIP">
]>
<dmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../schema/proced.xsd">
         <content>
            <figure>
              <title/>
                <graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-XXX49-001-01"/>
            </figure>
            <proceduralStep>
                <para>Check the brake system function.</para>
                <multimedia>
                   <title>Brake function</title>
                   <multimediaObject autoPlay="1" fullScreen="0" infoEntityIdent="ICN-XXX12-001-01" multimediaType="other"/>
                </multimedia>
             </proceduralStep>
             <multimedia>
                 <multimediaObject infoEntityIdent="ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01"
                        multimediaType="3D"
                        xlink:href="ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01.wrlzip"
                        xlink:type="simple"/>
                </multimedia>
         </content>
</dmodule>
```

The entities are referenced on `@infoEntityIdent` from various elements but there is not always an indication of the type of file:

```
    <graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-XXX49-001-01"/>
    <multimediaObject autoPlay="1" fullScreen="0" infoEntityIdent="ICN-XXX12-001-01"
                                           multimediaType="other"/>
    <multimediaObject infoEntityIdent="ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01"
                        multimediaType="3D" xlink:href="ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01.wrlzip"
 xlink:type="simple"/>
```

I can get the doctype inserted correctly, but I don't know how to access the entities and notations:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(child::*)"/>
    <xsl:text> [</xsl:text> 
    <!-- entities and notations here -->  
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Current output:

```
<!DOCTYPE dmodule []>
<dmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../schema/proced.xsd">
     <content>
        <figure>
          <title/>
            <graphic infoEntityIdent="ICN-XXX49-001-01"/>
        </figure>
        <proceduralStep>
            <para>Check the brake system function.</para>
            <multimedia>
               <title>Brake function</title>
               <multimediaObject autoPlay="1" fullScreen="0" infoEntityIdent="ICN-XXX12-001-01" multimediaType="other"/>
            </multimedia>
         </proceduralStep>
         <multimedia>
           <multimediaObject infoEntityIdent="ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01"
                    multimediaType="3D"
                    xlink:href="ICN-AAA235-000000-0-A-001-01.wrlzip"
                    xlink:type="simple"/>
            </multimedia>
     </content>
```

This is the inherited javascript in the stylesheet, and it does give the desired result:

```
<msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="js">

    <![CDATA[
function doctype(root) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    var basepath = unescape(
        root
            .item(0)
            .url
            .replace(/^file:\/{3,}/, '')
            .replace(/^file:/, '')
            .replace(/[^\/]+$/, '')
            .replace(/\//g, '\\')
    );
    var entities = [];
    var notations = [];
    var needSVGNotations = false;
    if (root.item(0).doctype) {
        entities = root.item(0).doctype.entities;
        notations = root.item(0).doctype.notations;
    }
    var syntax = '\n<!DOCTYPE ' + root.item(0).documentElement.nodeName + ' [\n';
    for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
        var entity = entities.item(i);

            var s = entity.xml;
            syntax += s + '\n';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < notations.length; i++) {
        var s = notations.item(i).xml;
        syntax += s + '\n';
    }
    syntax += ']>\n';
    return syntax;
}
    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>
```

And this is the template using the javascript:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="js:doctype(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: DTDs/Doctypes are not part of the XSLT/XPath (and XQuery) data model, in no version really. It is not quite clear whether your attempt worked with XSLT 1.0 and msxsl (and whether that was really the W3C XSLT 1.0 language used and not the proprietary, WD (working draft) version that MSXSL 3 and earlier also supported). Therefore it would help if you clarify that. There is no built-in way to copy DOCTYPEs in XSLT 1 or 2 or 3, you would need to depend on proprietary extensions to read out and/or output such details.

Comment: Like many things with Saxon, if you move off the official specs, there is often an extension in the commercial version, i.e. PE and EE have https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensions/instructions/doctype.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensions/instructions/entity-ref.html, for instance. I don't know whether that is an option for you and it is anyway only for outputting details in a cleaner way then having to rely completely on doe.

Comment: Reading out details about the DTD is limited, though there is e.g. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/functions/fn/unparsed-entity-public-id.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/functions/fn/unparsed-entity-uri.html.

Comment: If you are working with the Java version of Saxon you can also look into the LexEv https://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ preprocessor that should help in preserving "the DOCTYPE in the output". But I am not sure it is well supported with the latest Saxon version(s), the author seems to continue to have it online and hopefully it continues to work.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I will investigate the links you provided. The javascript works, and I'm using  msxsl.exe 1.1.0.1. I will find out if I can get PE or EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Honnen's suggestion to use `unparsed-entity-uri()` was everything as it returned all the information needed. He also tweaked my code to make it more succinct and corrected the RegEx which I originally had in `analyze-string`.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="getDocType"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="getDocType">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE </xsl:text>
    <!-- doctype will either be pm or dmodule -->
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(child::*)"/>
    <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
    <!-- get a list of all @infoEntityIdent(s). Declare as attribute()* for unparsed-entity-uri() -->
    <xsl:variable name="infoEntityIdent" as="attribute()*" select="(descendant::symbol | descendant::barCode | descendant::multimedia/multimediaObject | descendant::graphic)/@infoEntityIdent"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    
    <!-- write out the entity declaration -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$infoEntityIdent">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!ENTITY </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text> SYSTEM "</xsl:text>
      <xsl:variable name="uri" as="xs:anyURI" select="unparsed-entity-uri(.)"/>
      <!-- remove everything before, and including, the Original directory, leaving any graphics directory -->      
      <xsl:value-of select="replace($uri,'^.*Original/(.*)$','$1')"/>
      <xsl:text>" NDATA </xsl:text>
      <!-- print out the extension -->
      <xsl:value-of select="replace($uri, '.*?([^.]+)$', '$1')"/>
      <!-- close the declaration -->
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
    <!-- get a list of notations -->
    <xsl:variable name="notations" select="$infoEntityIdent ! unparsed-entity-uri(.) ! replace(., '.*?([^.]+)$', '$1')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($notations)">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'JPE?G','i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} PUBLIC "+//ISBN 0-7923-9432-1::Graphic Notation//NOTATION Joint Photographic Experts Group Raster//EN"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'cgm', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//NOTATION Computer Graphics Metafile//EN"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'wrlzip', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} SYSTEM "WRLZIP"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'svg', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} SYSTEM "SVG"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'tiff', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} SYSTEM "TIFF"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'png', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} PUBLIC "-//W3C//NOTATION Portable Network Graphics//EN"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'swf', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} PUBLIC "-//S1000D//NOTATION X-SHOCKWAVE-FLASH 3D Models Encoding//EN"&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>    
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The information in the DTD/DOCTYPE isn't part of the XSLT data model, so it's not passed from the XML parser to the XSLT processor -- which means you can't do this in pure XSLT.

There's a utility called LEXEV from Andrew Welch which preprocesses an XML document to create a representation of the DTD in terms of elements and attributes, which you can then transform in the normal way (or leave unchanged) using XSLT. to be post-processed back into DTD syntax at the end. I haven't used it for many years but I expect it still works.

Comment: I tried the LexEv.jar downloaded from https://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ this morning with both Java 8 and Java 11 and Saxon 11 HE but couldn't get it to work by simply setting `-x:com.andrewjwelch.lexev.LexEv` on the Saxon command line, I got an error "Transformation failed with configuration problem: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Failed to instantiate class com.andrewjwelch.lexev.LexEv". Running it from a Java application I got better error diagnostics that is was looking for Apache Xerces (`org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser`), once I added the jars of Apache Xerces it started to work.